# How can I create an installation file in vb. Net

Tags: vb.net

I created my project with ms access database and it worked well in the visual studio environment. When I created an installation file/set up and installed it, the system is no longer saving data into the database. How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't know. You've not posted any code, I have yet to develop the power of mind-reading, connecting to your computer and looking at your code...

Comment: We don't know where you put your database.  Or what your connection string looks like.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if database is working and linked properly?
2nd, If your User Interface is developed in .Net?
3rd, Use InstallShield to compress your Application data to install it.